# Can I secure a REST API (Say in springboot) using AAD and access it as a user from that AAD

Tags: rest, azure, security

I want to secure a set of REST API using the azure's AAD authentication where users within the directory can access the APIs using their credentials. I am able to fetch the fetch the API token using a simple reach login page, but when trying to pass the the fetched token in the header doesn't work.

I was able to secure a springboot web-app using the similar approach but I am not able to do it for a REST API.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Spring, but you'd need a standard JWT Bearer token authentication component there to authenticate the tokens sent in the header.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. I recently did that. But your question is a bit general. How are you working with the REST API? A native app in Azure or some other way?

Comment: You can use Azure API Management to do achieve this scenario in less effort,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

Answer (score 0):

yes you certainly can. Any api, web application,native application can be registered to azure active directory as a client. Once you do that you will get an unique application ID and a client secret with which your application can identify itself as a valid client of the Azure AD. And you can also enable Oauth 2.0 and use it. 
As far as spring Boot is concerned there is Spring Boot starter for Azure AD is now integrated with Spring Security (5.0 and above ) and it enables easy configuration spring boot apps with AAD.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory?view=azure-java-stable